# How to query the aggregation value of the same measurement point data grouping by time under different devices in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, aggregation, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Currently the raw data I stored in Apache IoTDB is like:

Time 1, Device 1. Measuring point;

Time 1, Device 2. Measuring point;

Time 2, Device 1. Measuring point;

Time 2, Device 2. Measuring point

I want to calculate the aggregated data value of (device 1. measuring point + device 2. measuring point) and (device 1. measuring point + device 2. measuring point) group by Time 1 and Time 2. I checked the official website of IoTDB, and it seems like using "GROUP BY LEVEL" command can only returned one sum value of all data values. How can I write the command to make IoTDB returned separate sum values grouped by Time 1 and Time 2?

how to deal this problem，someone help please？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following command:

`select sum(measuring points) from root.db.device1, root.db.device2 group by time([start, end), interval), level=1`

You can use `sum` in Apache IoTDB to combine data in two devices, and use `group by time` in Apache IoTDB to set certain time interval groups, and `level` represents to calculate data in different measuring points.